# Greater than or equal not working in power automate

Tags: power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I am newbie in powerautomate. I want to built the flow of if the amount is more than 500000, it will go to ED (approval), if not, it will go to another person.

I have tried with greater than or equal to but it does not work. it keeps showing this error. (I used PowerApps as a form). I tried as below .
requestamt(from powerApps) is greater than or equal to int('500000')
the error shows
ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied
The execution of template action 'Approval_from_ED' skipped: the branching condition for this action is not satisfied.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots and formulas that you use?